# React navigation createStackNavigator switch between routes

Tags: reactjs, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, redux-toolkit

I'm using React native with Expo and i'm trying to make a dynamic redirect navigation in my component.
When the user come to my page I want to check an async value and with the result of this value I want the user to be redirected to one of the Screen.
I'm using AppLoading from expo and redux state. But it's seems that I can't use navigate at this moment on my Stack.
Here is my code :

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function Mynavigation({ navigation }: BasicNavigationProps) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { appLoading } = useSelector(userStateSelector)

    const navigateToRoute = async () => {
        const goToPage2 = await needToGoPage2()

        if (goToPage2) {
            navigation.navigate('Page2')
        } else {
            navigation.navigate('Page1')
        }
    }

    return (
        appLoading ? (
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Page1" headerMode="none">
                <Stack.Screen name="Page1" component={Page1}/>
                <Stack.Screen name="Page2" component={Page2}/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        ) : (
            <AppLoading
                startAsync={ navigateToRoute }
                onFinish={() => dispatch(saveAppLoading(false))}
                onError={() => {
                    console.log('error')
                }}
            />
        )
    )
}
```

Did I forgot something ?
I Implemented another solution with two different Stack navigation, but I don't know witch version is better to use ?

```
const Stack1 = createStackNavigator();
const Stack2 = createStackNavigator();

export default function Mynavigation({ navigation }: BasicNavigationProps) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const [check, setCheck] = useState(false)
    const { appLoading } = useSelector(userStateSelector)

    const navigateToRoute = async () => {
        const goToPage2 = await needToGoPage2()

        setCheck(goToPage2)
    }

    return (
        appLoading ? (
            check ? (
                <Stack1.Navigator initialRouteName="Page1" headerMode="none">
                    <Stack1.Screen name="Page1" component={Page1Stack1}/>
                    <Stack1.Screen name="Page2" component={Page2Stack1}/>
                </Stack1.Navigator>
            ) : (
                <Stack2.Navigator initialRouteName="Page1" headerMode="none">
                    <Stack2.Screen name="Page1" component={Page1Stack2}/>
                    <Stack2.Screen name="Page2" component={Page2Stack2}/>
                </Stack2.Navigator>
            )
        ) : (
            <AppLoading
                startAsync={ navigateToRoute }
                onFinish={() => dispatch(saveAppLoading(false))}
                onError={() => {
                    console.log('error')
                }}
            />
        )
    )
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You can't use navigation props at this stage.

Remove it from the component props and try doing it like this:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function Mynavigation({ navigation }: BasicNavigationProps) {
     const [initialRouteName, setInitialRouteName] = React.useState('');
     const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

     const navigateToRoute = async () => {
          const goToPage2 = await needToGoPage2()
          if (goToPage2) {
               setInitialRouteName('Page2')
          } else {
               setInitialRouteName('Page1')
          }
          setLoading(false);
     }

     return (
          loading === false && initialRouteName.length > 0 ? (
               <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={initialRouteName} headerMode="none">
                    <Stack.Screen name="Page1" component={Page1} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Page2" component={Page2} />
               </Stack.Navigator>
          ) : (
                    <AppLoading
                         startAsync={navigateToRoute}
                         onFinish={() => dispatch(saveAppLoading(false))}
                         onError={() => {
                              console.log('error')
                         }}
                    />
               )
     )
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried this too, but `initialRouteName` is called just one time when the component is mounted. If I need to check my async function every time `loading` change, at the second async, the `initialRouteName` will not be changed. So what's the better solution in that case ?

Comment: Sorry. Not sure why it is not working for you so can't really help further.